# Android UDP connection

Tags: android, udp

So, I am trying to send a simple string to a C# application made by a friend ,through an UDP connection.

This is the method I am using to try and send the string.

```
public void runUdpClient()  {
    String udpMsg = "ALOOOOOO ";
    DatagramSocket ds = null;
    try {
        ds = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
        DatagramPacket dp;
        dp = new DatagramPacket(udpMsg.getBytes(), udpMsg.length(), serverAddr, 55901);
        ds.send(dp);

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ds != null) {
            ds.close();
        }
    }
}
```

(Didn't say the actualy IP, masked it just for safety of my friend's PC)

Now, the error I get is the following:

```
05-20 14:43:44.399: E/DatabaseUtils(2347): Writing exception to parcel
05-20 14:43:44.399: E/DatabaseUtils(2347): java.lang.SecurityException:             Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
05-20 14:43:44.399: E/DatabaseUtils(2347):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
05-20 14:43:44.399: E/DatabaseUtils(2347):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
05-20 14:43:44.399: E/DatabaseUtils(2347):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
05-20 14:43:44.399: E/DatabaseUtils(2347):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
05-20 14:43:44.399: E/DatabaseUtils(2347):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
05-20 14:43:44.399: E/DatabaseUtils(2347):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
05-20 14:43:44.399: E/DatabaseUtils(2347):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Now,this is the first time I am trying to send stuff through a UDP connection ,so I might have messed up something (?), but I doubt so, as I have checked and rechecked...

If other information is needed, let me know.

EDIT: Permissions are added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>                <usespermissionandroid:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

The application needs the necessary permissions to send data with UDP. The permissions are defined in the AndroidManifest.xml in your android project.

If you haven't yet added additional permissions please add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

For more information about the permissions in android please have a look to the android developers network:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Comment: I have the permissions added...I ll edit the topic so that they know perms are added...